# Last created object id

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My ID column is auto-increment, but I have to send ID to another function after object created and saved.

```
actionObj = ScAnsAction()

#actionObj.id -- auto increment

actionObj.user_id = getUserID(request)
actionObj.action_id = 6
actionObj.req_id = request_id
actionObj.a_date = i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
actionObj.save()

setUserNotifs(request,#should be latest above objectID)
```

I have try latest function over query set, but I retreived list out of index.

## SetUserNotif function

```
def setUserNotifs(request,request_id):
    username = request.user.username
    object_id_list = ScAns.objects.filter(username=username).values_list('id',flat=True)
    actionUsers =  ScAnsAction.objects.filter(req_id=request_id).values_list('user_id',flat=True).exclude(user_id=object_id_list).distinct()
    requestCreaterUsername = ScRequests.objects.filter(id=request_id).values_list('sender',flat=True)
    requestCreaterID = ScAns.objects.filter(username=requestCreaterUsername).values_list('id',flat=True)

    # send notification to users who has been commented on that request
    for actionUser in actionUsers:
        actionObj = ScActionNotif()
        actionObj.action_id = request_id
        actionObj.user_id = actionUser
        actionObj.notif = "unread"
        actionObj.save()

    # send notification to the creator of the request
    actionObj = ScActionNotif()
    actionObj.action_id = request_id
    actionObj.user_id = requestCreaterID[0]
    actionObj.notif = "unread"
    actionObj.save()
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django2/src/profiles/views.py" in addComment
  99.       setUserNotifs(request,actionObj.id)

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django2/src/database/views.py" in setUserNotifs
  136.  actionObj.user_id = requestCreaterID[0]

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __getitem__
  295.         return list(qs)[0]

Exception Type: IndexError at /about/addComment/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Comment: the problem was in my Function as Daniel said. I changed function accept parameters count to three (request,request_id,actionObj.id)

Comment: and make sure that your primary key model field is AutoField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the id of `actionObj`, you should just use it:

```
setUserNotifs(request, actionObj.id)
```

Comment: "list index out of range"

Comment: Oh. Is that an error you are receiving, or did you just fancy saying it? Maybe you should tell us where that error is happening, since it isn't in the code you have posted; a good start would be the full error message and traceback.

Comment: OK, so that error is happening in the `setUserNotifs` function. You should post that function.